# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on Account: Rollup Helper cannot update parent record

Tags: apex, validation-rule, rolluphelper

My org is seeing this error when we convert leads - We do not have a validation rule on the account that says this. Where does this validation rule live if is not on the account? Does Rollup helper have validation rules? I am not familiar with this tool.

```
23:15:23.160 (2160425179)|DML_END|[245]
23:15:23.162 (2162368464)|DML_END|[82]
23:15:23.162 (2162425434)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[82]|System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on Account: Rollup Helper cannot update parent record 0051J000006RHQXQA4: NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE: # Accounts Picked Up This Week: value outside of valid range on numeric field: 100: []
```

Comment: Are you using any app exchange app which may have this validation?

Comment: Would this be caught using the tooling apu using the following query? SELECT Id, ValidationName, Active, Description, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName, ErrorDisplayField, ErrorMessage,NamespacePrefix FROM ValidationRule

Comment: Never tried it but I believe it should work, Please keep updating as this sounds interesting

Comment: This works in the tooling API - But the validation that is firing does not appear... So I am not crazy - This literally does not exist on my standard objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION is an error message that indicates that a record had a custom error during processing. This can be either a validation rule or, in this case, an Apex Trigger. To resolve the problem, find the # Accounts Picked Up This Week field on the User object, and increase the size from 2 to a larger value. In the future, remember that this specific status code can be generated from Apex Triggers (and classes that the trigger may call).

How I figured this out:

> Rollup Helper cannot update

This is Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary (DLRS), or a variant.

> record 0051J000006RHQXQA4

It tried to update a User record (005 is the prefix for type User).

> NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE

This is the underlying status code, a value is too large or too small.

> # Accounts Picked Up This Week

The field that triggered the error.

> value outside of valid range on numeric field: 100

It's clear you've only allowed values -99 to +99. Adding enough space for another digit on the left would increase the range to -999 through +999.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation, really great learning for me to identify the root cause from minimal information.